# How to prevent automatic appendings to .bashrc from being effective?

Tags: bash

I'm looking for a way to nullify the undesirable behaviour of some installers that append code to `.bashrc` to force-load their environment automatically. The problem cropped-up a few times, mostly with Conda, and in some cases the user ended-up with a broken account that prevented them from logging in anymore.

I tried to add an unclosed here-document at the end of .bashrc, like this:

```bsh
# .bashrc

#...

: <<'__END__'
```

Which works, but generates <s>parsing errors</s> annoying warnings.

What would be a clean way to do that (without making the .bashrc readonly)?

Comment: When you discover a script that auto-appends to your startup files, the appropriate thing to do is to email the maintainer of that script and inform them that their package is broken.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you end your `.bashrc` with

```
return 0
```

Bash will [ignore any lines added after that](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-return), since `.bashrc` is handled like a sourced script:

> `return` may also be used to terminate execution of a script being executed with the `.` (`source`) builtin, returning either *n* or the exit status of the last command executed within the script as the exit status of the script.

(`exit 0` causes the shell to exit, which isn’t what you want.)

Answer (score 6):

While Stephen's trick definitely works, the fundamental problem here is that the installer is run with privileges that allow it to modify your `.bashrc`. If it's doing that, it could be making all sorts of unwanted changes to other things that might cause broken interactions or be outright malicious (ranging from phone-home spyware shipped intentionally to outright malware from a supply chain compromise or inside threat).

The right solution is not to run "installers" with any privileges. Instead you can run them inside a throwaway container or user account, then copy only the wanted files out of the "staging" environment to the environment you want to use them in. I do something like this with a tool I wrote, [usand](https://github.com/richfelker/usand), which uses `unshare` to make new user and mount namespaces that block network access and write access to files outside of the current directory and everything under it. While it's not presently very flexible, many of the same concepts can be applied to do something suited to your particular workflow.

Comment: Why are you using the software at all if you don't trust the installer?

Comment: @B.Kaatz This answer seems to be talking about running an installer in a sandboxed environment and then moving the resulting files out of the sandbox. This doesn't make sense since a malicious installer can just generate malicious executables. As far as I can tell, this isn't about compiling software from source because you don't trust prebuilt binaries.

Comment: @eesiraed: In practice, commercial or other non-free software that installs and changes crap you don't want tends to do it via an installer, *not* by having the main program redo it every time.  Obviously this doesn't defend against truly malicious attacks, but may help against some unscrupulous installers for otherwise-ok software.  IDK, I very rarely install anything non-free, and haven't for quite a while.

Comment: @eesiraed: If you're concerned about the executables installed themselves being malicious, you can use a similar sandboxing approach for them. That's actually part of my normal workflow with usand. I run them in an isolated directory tree with just the data they're supposed to operate on, and no network access. If they need GUI it's more difficult but a setup with a proxy X display is possible (xnest or similar). But if your main concern is the installer doing stupid stuff, just doing this at install time suffices.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE I'm interested in your isolation workflow. Is there a way we can chat somewhere else? Currently I manually read through the installer to check for malicious code and unwanted behaviour, but that's time consuming.

Comment: @eesiraed: this doesn't really seem to be about unscrupulous installers (although R mentions them as the worst case), rather about a different of opinion who is responsible for getting your `.bashrc` sorted. So for example, `conda init bash` is a command specifically designed to modify your `.bashrc`. That's what it's for. But, in a comment on the question, William Pursell states that any such script is "broken", so clearly believes it should not exist at all. R prefers installers not to attempt such things, and the questioner has seen problems as a result of that.

Comment: So the installer does what it's documented to do, and is in no way dishonest, it's just that what it does includes a step that none of these people want. I don't think that's really accurately characterised as, "I don't trust the installer". Rather, "I think that step is misguided and want to protect myself from people who think it's wise to attempt to automate it". I guess installers do this to "help" users who aren't comfortable editing .bashrc, and who for whatever reasons expect software to install with a single command. Obviously R, William, and Fravadona aren't in that category.

Answer (score 2):

Using `return` prevents the extra content from being executed, but it doesn't prevent the file from filling up with all that junk over time.  It also creates the problem where you accidentally add something below the `return` and have to figure out why your changes aren't taking effect.

What I've done before is to add a line at the end like `# END_ACTUAL_CONTENT`.  I created a script that would locate this marker and delete everything located after it, and set that script to run periodically.

You can also use functions like this to neutralize those annoying installers:

```
function bashrc_save() { cp -f ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc.backup }
function bashrc_restore() { mv -f ~/.bashrc.backup ~/.bashrc }
```

Install your program with `bashrc_save; ./install.sh; bashrc_restore` and any changes that it makes to your `.bashrc` file will be automatically rolled back.

I currently take this a step farther.  I store my `.bashrc` file (as well as a bunch of other configuration files) in a separate directory `~/.configfiles`, and I create symlinks to the locations where these files normally reside.  The contents of that folder are in a git repository.  I do that to make it easy to synchronize between systems, but it has the added benefit of being able to use `git diff` to see all the changes an installer has made and to use `git restore` to revert them en masse.